# Extra output on input redirection

Tags: pipe, io-redirection, input

I have a folder with three files:

```
$ ls
a  b  c
```

If I pipe the output of `ls` to `wc`, I get the right result:

```
$ ls | wc -l
3
```

However, when I specify the input to `wc` as the output of `ls`, I get extra text:

```
$ wc -l <(ls)
3 /dev/fd/63
```

Can anyone explain to me what is happening?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`wc` will tell you what file it's working on if it's able.  With the first one with the pipe it's reading from stdin, not a file, so does not report a filename.  The second one, however, you're using process substitution which presents the output of the command as a file, which `wc` reports.  It reports on the file descriptor it was given from which to read.